# Select AS temp_name FROM table WHERE temp_name = something?

Tags: mysql

You know how you can assign a temporary column name to a return value in a SQL statement like this?

```
SELECT something+this+that AS myvalue FROM mytable
```

Is it possible to use the temporary name `myvalue` as a conditional?

```
SELECT something+this+that AS myvalue FROM mytable WHERE myvalue = 10
```

I can't seem to figure out the syntax to do this. The only way I can figure out how to do it is to rewrite out the entire column definition again like this:

```
SELECT something+this+that AS myvalue FROM mytable WHERE something+this+that = 10
```

Obviously the above example is a trivial example. My query I need to do this on is extremely complexed, so having the rewrite each returned column definition for each conditional will be quite a hassle.

So anyways, what is the syntax for this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a derived table...

```
SELECT
    myvalue
FROM
    (
    SELECT something+this+that AS myvalue FROM mytable
    ) foo
WHERE
    myvalue = 10
```

Or use a CTE which looks more elegant but is the same

```
;WITh myCTE AS
(
    SELECT something+this+that AS myvalue FROM mytable
)
SELECT
    myvalue
FROM
    myCTE
WHERE
    myvalue = 10
```

Or a computed column so it's usable normally

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD myvalue AS something+this+that
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, but you may cheat by putting the data into a temporary table, and then running a second query to run the rest.

That, or dynamic SQL, but I'm not a fan of the latter.

Answer (score -1):

> SELECT something+this+that AS myvalue FROM mytable WHERE myvalue = 10

You could try something like that:

```
SELECT something+this+that AS myvalue
FROM  `users` 
HAVING myvalue=10;
```